# Migrating code to GL20 graphic strange flashing behaviour

Tags: libgdx

I was trying to do some code based on the one that exist in the book from LibGDX. Adding some screen transitions to the flow (worked in gles1) and since LibGDX deprecated GL10, I was attempting to refactor it to GL20.

I made some changes most of them given to deprecated functions or functions called in a different way. But my final result is not close to workable since it make my screen to flash.

I was focus myself for now in the desktop version due to this issue.

SplashScreen01.java

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Stack;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;
import com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.screens.transitions.ScreenTransition;
import com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.screens.transitions.ScreenTransitionSlice;
import com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.util.Constants;


public class SplashScreen01 extends AbstractGameScreen {

private static final String TAG = SplashScreen01.class.getName();

private Stage stage;
Texture splashTexture;

Sprite splashSprite;
boolean inTransition;
float screenTimingLeft;

private Image imgBackground;

// debug
private final float DEBUG_REBUILD_INTERVAL = 5.0f;
private boolean debugEnabled = false;
private float debugRebuildStage;

public SplashScreen01(DirectedGame app) {
    super(app);

}

/*
 * cycled function for each graphic frame renders the SplashScreen depending in the deltatime
 * @param deltatime - graphics timer counter
 */
@Override
public void render(float deltaTime) {

    checkNextScreen(deltaTime);

    //clear screen with color GREY
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(126 / 255.0f, 126 / 255.0f, 126 / 255.0f, 1.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (debugEnabled) {
        debugRebuildStage -= deltaTime;
        if (debugRebuildStage <= 0) {
            debugRebuildStage = DEBUG_REBUILD_INTERVAL;
            rebuildStage();
        }
    }
    stage.act(deltaTime);
    stage.draw();
    // Table.drawDebug(stage);

}

/*
 * Change the internal Viewport in case of a screen size alteration
 */
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.setViewport(new StretchViewport(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT));
}

/*
 * First initialization of this class, first status initializer
 */
@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage();

    try {
        splashTexture = new Texture("images/LogoSingleGrey768h.png");
        splashTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //graphic Splash Screen: SomeOne Tempered the Game files system
    }
    screenTimingLeft = Constants.SPLASH_SCREEN_01_TOTAL_DURATION;
    rebuildStage();
}

@Override
public void hide() {

    splashTexture.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

/**
 * Rebuild Stage preparing elements and gathering them together
 */
private void rebuildStage() {

    // build all layers
    Table layerBackground = buildBackgroundLayer();

    // assemble stage for menu screen
    stage.clear();
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    stage.addActor(stack);
    stack.setSize(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT);
    stack.add(layerBackground);
}

//check if it is time for next screen
private void checkNextScreen(float deltaTime) {
    screenTimingLeft -= deltaTime;
    if (!inTransition && screenTimingLeft < 0) {
        inTransition = true;
        //call next screen
        ScreenTransition transition = ScreenTransitionSlice.init(Constants.SPLASH_SCREEN_02_ANIM_DURATION, ScreenTransitionSlice.UP_DOWN, 20, Interpolation.pow5Out);
        game.setScreen(new SplashScreen02(game), transition);
    }
}

/**
 * Aggregates objects and actors for background layer
 * 
 * @return layer - Table layer with the elements
 */
private Table buildBackgroundLayer() {
    Table layer = new Table();

    TextureRegion splashRegion = new TextureRegion(splashTexture, 0, 0, 768, 384);

    imgBackground = new Image(splashRegion);

    layer.add(imgBackground);
    return layer;
}

@Override
public InputProcessor getInputProcessor() {
    return stage;
}
```

}

ScreenTransitionSlice.java

```
    /*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright 2013 Andreas Oehlke
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 ******************************************************************************/

package com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.screens.transitions;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class ScreenTransitionSlice implements ScreenTransition {

    public static final int UP = 1;
    public static final int DOWN = 2;
    public static final int UP_DOWN = 3;

    private static final ScreenTransitionSlice instance = new ScreenTransitionSlice();

    private float duration;
    private int direction;
    private Interpolation easing;
    private Array<Integer> sliceIndex = new Array<Integer>();

    public static ScreenTransitionSlice init(float duration, int direction, int numSlices, Interpolation easing) {
        instance.duration = duration;
        instance.direction = direction;
        instance.easing = easing;
        // create shuffled list of slice indices which determines the order of slice animation
        instance.sliceIndex.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < numSlices; i++)
            instance.sliceIndex.add(i);
        instance.sliceIndex.shuffle();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public float getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch, Texture currScreen, Texture nextScreen, float alpha) {
        float w = currScreen.getWidth();
        float h = currScreen.getHeight();
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        int sliceWidth = (int) (w / sliceIndex.size);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(currScreen, 0, 0, 0, 0, w, h, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, currScreen.getWidth(), currScreen.getHeight(), false, true);
        if (easing != null)
            alpha = easing.apply(alpha);
        for (int i = 0; i < sliceIndex.size; i++) {
            // current slice/column
            x = i * sliceWidth;
            // vertical displacement using randomized list of slice indices
            float offsetY = h * (1 + sliceIndex.get(i) / (float) sliceIndex.size);
            switch (direction) {
                case UP:
                    y = -offsetY + offsetY * alpha;
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    y = offsetY - offsetY * alpha;
                    break;
                case UP_DOWN:
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        y = -offsetY + offsetY * alpha;
                    } else {
                        y = offsetY - offsetY * alpha;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            batch.draw(nextScreen, x, y, 0, 0, sliceWidth, h, 1, 1, 0, i * sliceWidth, 0, sliceWidth, nextScreen.getHeight(), false, true);
        }
        batch.end();
    }

}
```

So since I don't really know which file is not making it work, anyone that wants to help the code is in:
https://bitbucket.org/LisarteBarbosa/canyonbunny/src/7da43bb21833cfc7c0037e55182f380d31d7e34b/core/src/com/packtpub/libgdx/canyonbunny/?at=master

https://bitbucket.org/LisarteBarbosa/canyonbunny/src

Answer (score 0):

Number one - **commented out code** is extremely confusing and I have no idea whether it is still commented out. The render method in your CanyonBunnyMain would definitely cause flickering if the draw code is not commented out. Because it would keep getting called as it is your main entry point.

```
public void render() {
/*
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1); 
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); batch.begin(); batch.draw(img, 0, 0); batch.end();
         */
}
```

Make that render() method empty forever. The only code you need in this class is what you have in the create() method. You'll still need an empty @Override for render(), though.

Number two - I suspect that you do NOT need super(app) in either SplashScreen01 or SplashScreen02. I would do it like this (for both of them)

```
private float debugRebuildStage;
**private DirectedGame app;**
```

and then in your constructor change this

```
public SplashScreen01(DirectedGame app) {
    super(app);

}
```

to this

```
public SplashScreen01(DirectedGame app) {
 **this.app = app;** 
}
```

So, the app declaration above becomes the app that was passed in to the constructor. For both SplashScreen01 and SplashScreen02. And so your game can continue with its "integrity" intact.

I hope that helps, ... and fixes your problem.

John